# Is there a HTML construct similar to a Select dropdown, but that I can type into?

Tags: html

The client is looking for a control on the page which resembles and behaves like a dropdown select box, but that you can type into.

The page is initially going to load with thousands of items in a dropdown select box. Rather than display all the results, they want to type part of the word they're looking for into the textbox and to filter the result set.

The client specifically stated that they want to have a select box that can accept text. Does such a control exist? Is it something I'm going to have to hack together myself? Can somebody suggest how best to solve this problem?

Comment: There  is no native element, but plenty of JavaScript replacements. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: @Pekka, yes, jQuery isn't a problem.. is there a pluggin for this?

Comment: I second jQuery; specifically the jQueryUI autocomplete control: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete

Comment: thanks dude, this appears to be exactly what I need

Comment: @dudeNumber4 You should write this as an answer.

Comment: @dudeNumber4, I agree with @bazmegakapa. You're in for some easy reputation points! ;-)

Comment: @DaveDev Yeah, and better do it before some rep-leecher comes and takes it :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa I'll keep my eye out for the leechers. Nobody's getting rep for this except the dude.

Comment: jQuery... Write this yourself?

Comment: This will be the HTML5 datalist's job in the future, but support for that is almost non-existent at this point. That jQuery autocomplete control or a combobox plugin should do the trick for you.

Comment: A lot of people are suggesting jQuery UI. While it's a very very good library, if you're only looking for one element, it's better to get a standalone one, like this: http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/index.shtml. I don't know if it's what you're looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by [dudeNumber4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74000/dudenumber4), there is no way to do this with just HTML. The best way would be to use [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete)